# Как отправить данные из формы на сервер?

Tags: android

Всем привет!

подскажите как правильно отправить данные из своей формы (наследник DialogFragment), на сервер?

запутался в примерах

по идеи данные должны уходить через POST запрос, но класс HttpPost - deprecated.

предлагаемый URLConnection, даже при задании метода POST, судя по примерам, данные передает через адрес, то есть GET методом

какой подход сейчас является правильным?

сужу по этим примерам:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();
```

...

```
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Спасибо

P.S.

правильно ли будет размещать POST запрос в onClick наследника DialogFragment, у меня Android Studio начал ругаться уже на строку `new URL("http://yoururl.com")`

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать библиотеку OkHttp, она намного легче и проще.
Вот пример с офф. сайта, если что не понятно поясню.

```
public static final MediaType JSON= MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
              .url(url)
              .post(body)
              .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
     }
```

Либа [вот](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Comment: спасибо, даже не слышал о этой библиотеке, попробую вечером, по синтаксису вроде все понятно, будут вопросы обязательно задам )